# to download samples the user should login or create an account first

Tags: magento2, customer-login

[image]

i want to restrict the user so that if he wants to download the sample data he would have to login or create an account first otherwise he would be not be able to download the sample data.

Comment: How are you adding the link to the samples download?

Comment: just by creating downloadable product in magento create product option and adding the file there

Comment: you would need to override the template that loads the downloadable product link and then use the logic in my answer to display or hide the downloadable product.

Comment: can i prompt the user to login or create account first when the downloadable product is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform logic on the login status of a customer in a template use a helper class to detect if the customer is logged in

```
private $httpContext;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
) {
    $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
}

/**
 * is logged in using CONTEXT_AUTH
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isLoggedIn()
{
    return $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);;
}
```

Depending on how you make your helper available to your template you can call the isLoggedIn() method and use it to display or hide content. Here I am using a *ViewModel* helper injected into the default Template block class.

```
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
?>
<ol>
    <li><?php echo ($viewModel->isLoggedIn() ? 'LOGGED IN':'NOT LOGGED IN')?></li>
</ol>
```